# How to use NSOpenPanel to select a file with ext "zip.001"

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsopenpanel

I use  `NSopenPanel` to select a file with common ext, for example:

```
openDlg.allowedFileTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"zip", nil];
```

But how to select a file named as "**test.zip.001**"?

`allowedFileTypes` set to **@"001"** and **@"zip.001"** neither works.

Comment: Did you try `NSOpenSavePanelDelegate`'s method `- (BOOL)panel:(id)sender shouldEnableURL:(NSURL *)url`?

Comment: Sorry, how to implement the delegate ? I am quite new in obj-c

Comment: Ok, this delegate works!